# Recovering RMAN Backup Into a New Database

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery, rman

I have a RMAN backup from an old oracle DB that I need to open on a new PC with a new instance of oracle installed.

I am unsure how to go about this as from what I can see in the documentation associated with this there should be a control file but I cannot see one.

Would anyone know where start with this?

I have created a new database and connected RMAN to it but unsure of next steps

Comment: Drop your created DB. Then google "Restore Oracle DB into new machine". I can't give detailed steps (they relating to OS, directory, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You may not see the controlfile as it is in a backup piece. Do you have a logfile associated with the backup?

if you don't. You'll have to trial and error the process. Start with the following:

```
rman target /
startup nomount force;
restore spfile from '/backup/location/bckfile1.bkp';
shutdown immediate
```